# Как сверстать страницы сайта из плагина OptimizePress в HTML\CSS (избавится от плагина, оставив функционал)

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка, wordpress-плагины, конвертация

Взял заказ на оптимизацию сайта WordPress. Оптимизировал. И теперь заказчик предложил избавится от плагина OptimizePress и хочет что бы я заменил это простым кодом html\css/.
А у меня не много опыта работы с WP. А с подобными задачами вообще не сталкивался.
Подскажите, пожалуйста как это можно сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А с версткой у Вас достаточно опыта работы? Ну если я Вас верно понял и вместо билдера клиент хочет заменить это на темплейты, то фактически Вам нужно будет разработать WordPress тему, или добавить необходимые темплейты в дочернюю тему от текущей. Ну и конечно же есть свои особенности и тонкости, как и везде.

Comment: mikgroup.ch вот сайт и нужно его переверстать, так как заказчику не нравится сео оптимизация текущего плагина.